# Customazible Admin Page (web-interface) for a web scraper

Tags: python, mongodb, user-interface, database-administration, nosql

I wrote web scraper in python, which uses MongoDB as a data store for saving complex settings in JSON format. Now I need some interface for users, who will enter such settings into database.

It must be some web-page like Django Admin Page or something else, but it must strongly work with complex MongoDB documents structure.

Unfortunately, I can't use one of these [apps](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/), because they can't be customized to show only some of documents and edit user interface by necessary requirements (or maybe I'm wrong?)

So, is there any simple way to make such page?

Answer (score 0):

it is a specific requisite, but there is some options which cover json structure, but not permissions, which you can implement:

- http://jsonwidget.org/wiki/Jsonwidget

  - http://jsonwidget.org/wiki/Jsonwidget-javascript
  - http://jsonwidget.org/wiki/Jsonwidget-python
- http://jsonmate.com/ is a jquery plugin

Regards,
Moacy